# Remove rows from a data frame based on values in another data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, time-series

I have a data frame of start and end times of an event that I need to remove from a second larger timeseries data frame. I want to remove all rows between the start and end times from from smaller data frame in the larger data frame.

The start/end times data frame looks like this:

```
smaller <- structure(list(MinDate = structure(c(1664433052, 1664433041), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), MaxDate = structure(c(1664433054, 1664433047), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), Valve = c("FSV-999", "FSV-001")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```

And a larger data frame that looks like this:

```
larger <- structure(list(DateTime = structure(c(1664433040, 1664433041, 
1664433042, 1664433043, 1664433044, 1664433045, 1664433046, 1664433047, 
1664433048, 1664433049, 1664433050, 1664433050, 1664433051, 1664433051, 
1664433052, 1664433052, 1664433053, 1664433053, 1664433054, 1664433054, 
1664433055, 1664433056, 1664433057, 1664433058, 1664433059, 1664433060
), tzone = "", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), Valve = c("FSV-001", 
"FSV-001", "FSV-001", "FSV-001", "FSV-001", "FSV-001", "FSV-001", 
"FSV-001", "FSV-001", "FSV-001", "FSV-001", "FSV-999", "FSV-001", 
"FSV-999", "FSV-001", "FSV-999", "FSV-001", "FSV-999", "FSV-001", 
"FSV-999", "FSV-001", "FSV-001", "FSV-001", "FSV-001", "FSV-001", 
"FSV-001")), row.names = c(NA, -26L), class = "data.frame")
```

In the end, I am hoping to get this:

```
end <- structure(list(DateTime = structure(c(1664433040, 1664433048, 
1664433049, 1664433050, 1664433050, 1664433051, 1664433051, 1664433052, 
1664433053, 1664433054, 1664433055, 1664433056, 1664433057, 1664433058, 
1664433059, 1664433060), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
    Valve = c("FSV-001", "FSV-001", "FSV-001", "FSV-001", "FSV-999", 
    "FSV-001", "FSV-999", "FSV-001", "FSV-001", "FSV-001", "FSV-001", 
    "FSV-001", "FSV-001", "FSV-001", "FSV-001", "FSV-001")), row.names = c(1L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 17L, 19L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 
25L, 26L), class = "data.frame")
```

I've tried using this bit of code that has worked for me in certain situations in the past, but it doesn't remove the entire chunk of time.

```
larger %>%
  mutate(Status = "Keep") %>%
  mutate(Status = case_when(DateTime >= smaller$MinDate & DateTime <= smaller$MaxDate ~ "Throw", TRUE ~ as.character(Status))) %>%
  filter(Status != "Throw") %>%
  mutate(Status = NULL)
```

Perhaps using "%in%" would be helpful?

Comment: Your timestamps don't make sense. Based on the `smaller` dataset that you have shared, your `end` df should be empty since the times do not overlap. Take a look at your example datasets again. In any case, this should work for the right data: ```larger %>% 
  right_join({smaller %>% 
                mutate(across(contains("Date"), ~as.POSIXct(.x, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")))}, 
             by = "Valve") %>% 
  filter(DateTime > MinDate &  DateTime < MaxDate)```

Comment: Sorry @M--, I'm not sure what you mean. "2022-09-29 01:30:52" from smaller should equal to 1664433052 in larger. However, it doesn't work for me with my actual dataset because of memory issues (Error: cannot allocate vector of size 6.4 Gb)

Comment: Covert your min,max date columns to dttm objects. I believe because of different tz I get different time stamps.

Comment: @M-- I have updated the code for 'smaller' to make the timestamps the same. Is there a less computationally intense way of achieving the goal?

Comment: Also, this code keeps the times between min and max points, it doesn't remove them.

Comment: If you care about computation, `data.table` is the way to go, add that tag to your question. I will take a look later today.

Comment: your `end` data still doesn't make sense to me :(